# How to create sound wave art?

Tags: editing, audio-recording

I have a sound file of my daughter laughing and I want to convert it into an image like the one attached, not just the typical line style of sound waves. Does anyone know a program that makes sound waves like this, I have illustrator and photoshop, so could always take a screen shot if I found a program. Or even better if the program would let me import it to use as a vector file would be amazing! [image]

https://www.istockphoto.com/nz/vector/abstract-music-vector-background-with-sound-voice-audio-wave-equalizer-waveform-gm953559194-260322211

Comment: You want to ask here: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Any sound editing program can show you the audio waveform. [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) is a free cross-platform one, or you could use Adobe's Audition (subscription based though there is a free trial). They don't specifically export waveforms as images, but you could screenshot the waveform and beautify it with the image editor of your choice.

Alternatively you could use one of the many online visualiser pages. This one is a good example, it can export the waveform as an SVG graphic. https://www.misha.studio/waveformer/

Answer (score 0):

As this is the video production forum, one answer would be [Blender](https://inkscape.org/). If you do not know it is a free but awesome 3D modeling program, editor, compositor.

There are several options, visualizing the general beat or volume, or trying to make something more complex.

Take one dive into a search:

https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=blender+waveform+visualization

If you want something static you can make a screen capture of any visualizer and draw on top of it. You can use [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) for that as @stib already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I created a web application that does this (It's free!)

Other than waveform animations it also generates a subtitle if you want.

It's perfect for people that are not familiar with design/video editing.
You have to provide an audio file and create a template.
The application does the rest and notifies you when the video is ready.

Here's a link to a guide: https://vokal.co/blog/audio-waveform